# How can I get instant fb checkin information of users

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

For e.g. a user visits a restaurant and he checkins on Facebook, I want to notify him/her about the ongoing offers on that restaurants.

I have checked Facebook's user_tagged_place API but it only gives me info of past checkins. can anyone help me with this. I just want to get notified when someone checks in to some place/restaurants/location.

Comment: Checkins have been deprecated for quite a while now, in favor of posts with location information attached. // You can get notified (server-side) when a user of your app makes a new post – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5 But you will have to check whether they contain a specific location yourself.

Comment: Hi @CBore, Thanks a lot for replying. Can you please tell me more about the same. I need the user-checkin at real time. I am confused what I should use, I should subscribe for checkin_deal_claims in user object or checkins for page object. Can you give me some working tutorial link. It will be great help. I came across https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples and trying this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need what's called [`webhooks`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5). But you need a server on the web to use them

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can you plz give me some working example to setup webhook, Like script of callback url, and what is verify token? How to process response on server side. etc.

Comment: The best place where you can find such informations is the link in the answer. Probably you can find some examples somewhere else, but they might be not updated to the latest version, which is v2.5. In any case you need to be tagged as a "developer" by FB, and to do this you need an account that is verified (by adding your phone number or credit card number)